# memorystream to datatable in c#

Tags: c#

will you please help me out from get data from memory stream to datatable

below code i m following

```
        var config = new MarketplaceWebServiceConfig { ServiceURL = ServiceURL };
        var client = new MarketplaceWebServiceClient(AWSAccessKeyID, secretKey, appName, Version, config);
        var request = new GetReportRequest { Merchant = sellerID, ReportId = reportId };

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        request.Report = ms;

        var response = client.GetReport(request);
```

please help me out form ms to data table
i m not able to make it

Thanks,
Jimmy Darji

Answer (score 0):

First of all what format is the memorystream data in? As an example, The message stream below is in binary format So I receive the data into a Memeorystream object tell it to start at the beginning of the stream and then I deserialise it into the object that I want.

```
MemoryStream mem = (MemoryStream) incoming.BodyStream;
                    mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    IFormatter ifm = new BinaryFormatter();
                    var tt = (TravelMessageServiceObjects) ifm.Deserialize(mem);
```

tt can now be used to post into your db.